# How does the incremental form of the PID controller work?

Tags: c, pid-controller, plc

I have a question regarding the features of the so called incremental (velocity) form
of the PID controller. As far as I understand this form in correct manner it can be
described via this pseudocode

```
// increment of the action as a sum of the increment of the 
// P term with setpoint weighting:                                        dup = Kp * b * (r - r1) - Kp * (y - y1)), 
// I term with trapezoidal integration rule:                              dui = (Kp*T)/(2.0*Ti) * (e + e1),
// D term with filtering pole and protection against the derivative kick: dud = Td/(Nd*T + Td) * (ud1 - ud2) - (Kp*Td*Nd)/(Nd*T + Td)*(y - 2.0*y1 + y2)) 
// where 
// T  - execution period
// Kp - proportional gain
// b  - weighting factor (0 <= b <= 1)
// Ti - integration time constant
// Td - derivative time constant
// Nd - filtering pole position
// r  - reference value
// y  - controlled value
// e  - control error
// ud - derivative term
// 1  - value at time instant (k-1)
// 2  - value at time instant (k-2)  
du = dup + dui + dud

// current action as a sum of previous action and current increment of the action
u = u1 + du

// limitation of the action based on the actuator limits
if (u > u_max) {
    u = u_max
} else if (u < u_min) {
    u = u_min
}
// memory variables update
r1  = r
y2  = y1
y1  = y
e1  = e
u1  = u
ud2 = ud1
ud1 = ud
```

What I don't fully understand is behavior of this form in following scenario. Let's say
I have this code in the feedback control loop and I do on-line changes of the controller parameters
`Kp` and `Ti` (for the sake of simplicity suppose the D term isn't present). Now for whatever reason
I set the `Kp = 0.0` i.e. I effectively force the `dup` and the `dui` to be zero from that time instant. According to the above given pseudocode the action will remain at the previous value. In other words the controller still produces some nonzero action.

As far as my understanding is correct it seems to me that this behavior can be little bit misleading. My question is why the algorithm has been designed in this way?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. From your question, it sounds like you understand the meaning of each of the statements in your pseudocode program, and it sounds like you understand what the program will do if `du` = 0. Do you want an explanation of how the statements `u = u1 + du` and `u1 = u` result in `u` not changing? Or do you want an explanation of why the algorithm was designed that way in the first place?

Comment: @CassieSwett thank you for your reaction. I am sorry for little bit unclear question.
I have just attempted to formulate the question in more clear way.